# Error at connecting to database using Spring

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jdbc

I am trying to run a springexample. I have configured my .xml file as follows. I am using mysql as my DB, but I'm getting the error mentioned below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="dataSource" destroy-method="close" 
        class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://127.0.0.1:3306"/>
        <property name="username" value="root"/>
        <property name="password" value="root"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="forumDAO" class="com.vaannila.dao.ForumDAOImpl">
         <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

error

EDIT

now changed to

```
<property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
<property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test"/>
<property name="username" value="root"/>
<property name="password" value="root"/>
```

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not
>   get JDBC Connection; nested exception is
>   org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create
>   PoolableConnectionFactory (socket creation error)
>         at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:82)
>         at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:572)
>         at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:786)
>         at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:842)
>         at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:850)
>         at com.vaannila.dao.ForumDAOImpl.insertForum(ForumDAOImpl.java:29)

Comment: Is your mysql instance running? Can you connect to it with any tool?

Comment: yes, i am coeected through some tool and so mysql is up and running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration file is setup for a HSQL database instead of a MySQL database.
Use:

```
<property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
<property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/DATABASE_NAME"/>
```

You should also check, that you have the correct JDBC driver in your classpath.

Comment: applied chananges as mentioned in change of orignal post.Also added mysql deiver.Still facing same problem

Comment: Check that your MySQL database is running before you try to run this code. That might help.

Comment: changed config , as mentioned in edit .Still facing same error

Comment: mysql is running as am connected to it through mysqlworkbench

Comment: Are you sure, that the exception is still the one listed in your question?

Comment: yes . it is Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (socket creation error)

Comment: This my sound stupid, but are you sure, that you have deployed the changes to the config file? The `PoolableConnectionFactory` error usually only happens together with HSQL databases.

Comment: @akshay let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/961/discussion-between-nfechner-and-akshay)

Answer (score 0):

double check your connection url, try

> localhost:9001

instead of

> 127.0.0.1

... and you have not specified a database in yr connection string

Answer (score 0):

Your URL value is incorrect:

```
<property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://127.0.0.1"/>
```

Use this instead:

```
<property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/yourdbname"/>
```

Comment: its hsql not mysql, different default port

Answer (score 0):

I am using this bean for my connection to `mysql` and its working:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?user=root&password=root" />
    <property name="initialSize" value="2" />
    <property name="maxActive" value="5" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Download **mysql-connector-java-5.1.45** put in the lib, then it works.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the `mysql service` wasn't running. Check and make sure it is running.